# Ruby on Rails: apply drop shadow with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

How do I apply a drop shadow to my images saved with carrierwave? I can't find any examples on how to do this.

**Update:**
Example for adding a shadow to images with CSS. You can remove the padding and margin if you don't like the white 1px border around the image. It looks nice though...

```
.dropSmallShadow {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.255);
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Best regards
Asbjørn Morell

Comment: You mean when they are displayed on the webpage?

Comment: Something like this http://www.reviewmylife.co.uk/blog/2008/08/07/batch-processing-photos-with-dos-and-imagemagick/ Don't need the rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to not add the border/dropshadow in the image (since you may want to display them differently later on), but instead add them using CSS.

for example, you can add a 5 px white padding around the image, and then a box-shadow using http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

IE will degrade to just having the white border like a polaroid.